# cron and at send mail to wrong user

Tags: ubuntu, cron, postfix

I have cron and sometimes at on an ubuntu 14.04.

jobs output should be mail to me, but failed.

I make a `.forward` in my home dir. mail explicitly send to local unix user is forwarded to my corp mail fine.

```
 echo archemar@mycompany.com > .forward
 date | mail archy
```

I receive the mail at archemar@mycompany.com.

however, `cron` and `at` sends mail to (non existing) archy@mycompany.com

What am I missing here ?

edit: mailer is postfix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for cron you can to add a line to your crontab:

```
MAILTO=archemar@mycompany.com
```

maybe there is already a wrong MAILTO line in your crontab?

But it might be better to find a universal solution, such as this:

Add line(s) to `/etc/aliases` (one for each user for which you wish to substitute a destination email address):

```
root: archemar@mycompany.com
```

Rebuild the database with `newaliases`

Reload postfix with `postfix reload`

Comment: I use the MAILTO option, that was so simple ...

Comment: make sure you do this for root account, etc. too.  `crontab -e` for user, `sudo crontab -e` for root.